# Increasing throughput and speed on a long distance server in HK to NYC

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, upload, internet-speed

Pings from a server in Hong Kong to NYC is 200ms+. I know I can't change that much as I'd be breaking the laws of physics. I have a 100mbit connected ubuntu server in Hong Kong and I want to access it in NYC. The download speed on the server is about 25mbit and upload ranges from 2-9mbit.

What else can I do to increase this throughput mainly for upload speed? What bottlenecks should I be aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The upload times of 2-9 MB of the Hong Kong server seems like the real bottleneck.

I suggest:

- Get from the Hong Kong ISP a better connection and a plan that is much faster.
  Use optical fiber if possible.
- Ensure the same in NYC.
- Ensure that the network cards on the computers on both sides are fast enough
  to use the new connection speeds.
- If the computers in question are old and slow, replace them.
- Ditto for the routers that connect the computers to the internet.

In short: Upgrade, upgrade, upgrade.
You can get much better speeds without breaking the laws of physics,
but rather by breaking the budget.

Comment: there's nothing software wise I can do on the server side? my vps provider doesn't let us upgrade anything as its just a standard plan as a nat vps.

Comment: The only improvement software can do is to compress the data so there are less bytes to transmit.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ - Computing power has little to do with the bandwidth a server/client is connected to.  **Your real problem is the latency and no amount of processing power will fix that problem**  However, a 200 ms latency is a 1/5 of a second, which honestly isn't that high (there are certainly higher latency connections).  You could try using a different DNS provider, however, you will only get so much out of the connection as it is.    In order to get anywhere near the capacity of the server the client must have a connection that is equal or better.

Comment: @Ramhound: There exist faster network connections, but they are costly.

Comment: my client is on fiber and its fast gigabit. Its just he HK vps that is causing me headaches on how to speed things up. because its a NAT vps, its very limited on what I can upgrade which is nothing.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ - Your question does not actually indicate your server is a VPS, which makes a huge difference, and is indeed a huge performance bottleneck.  One simple solution is to upgrade to a dedicated server by providing your own hardware.  Of course that isn't cheap.

Comment: What protocol do you use? Standard TCP-based protocols don't maximize bandwidth usage. See [this](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/GYQA5QVJ) (yes, it's a commercial brochure, but it starts with a good explanation).